# Replace spaces in href with %20 in php

Tags: php, html, escaping, preg-replace, href

i want to replace every space in a link with %20.

```
<a href="Replace the spaces here">Some text</a>
```

i want to get This:

```
<a href="Replace%20the%20spaces%20here">Some text</a>
```

not this:

```
<a%20href="Replace%20the%20spaces%20here">Some%20text</a>
```

How to do this?
preg_replace?
Solution (because I cant post an answer):

```
$search= '(href="(.*?)")s';
$replace= '';
$newstring= preg_replace_callback($search,create_function('$treffer','urlencode($treffer[0]);'),$string);
```

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Why do you have space-less links in the first place? How is this page being generated?

Comment: I would agree with @Pekka웃 here.  It is REALLY bad practice to have URL's with spaces in them in the first place.

Comment: I don't see the purpose of doing this. Modern day browsers do this automatically, unless your users and/or you are using a dinosaur browser. Plus, having files with spaces to start off with, is really bad practice. I suggest you start naming your files using underscores, and/or hyphens.

Comment: What's wrong with file names with spaces? As long as they are properly escaped?

Comment: *"As long as they are properly escaped"* - It's an extra step that can be avoided in the first place, but that's just me ;-) @Pekka웃

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the note, every modern browser will process the following just fine:

```
<a href="Replace the spaces here">Some text</a>
```

If you insist in doing it regardless, and assuming you cannot `urlencode()` the links *before* they're output, you need to use either of:

- `preg_replace_callback()` or
- a DOM parser

Using either will allow you to only apply `urlencode()` where it's needed.

Comment: This is a bad suggestion.

Comment: @SalmanA: no it's not. It tells him to not bother, which is correct, and how to do it if he still wants to, which is also correct.

Comment: You should always encode the URLs properly; unless you are sure where the content between `href='...'` comes from.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `urlencode()` function for the href part.

http://php.net/urlencode

Comment: Seeing his current result, I suspect he's already doing that.

Comment: This is unlikely to help - you can't just apply `urlencode()` to the HTML code above.

Comment: If you're in PHP, you should definitely be using the existing encode and decode functions on your URLs (even if they don't have spaces).

Comment: @prrstn true, but how would you apply `urlencode()` to the HTML code the OP shows? It's not a valid answer to the OP's situation

Comment: _... for the *href* part_..., sounds OK to me.

Comment: @SalmanA true, but by that standard an answer saying "to solve this problem, you need to use PHP." is also OK

Comment: I think this answer matches the question's precision. At least this is why I posted. Anyway we are guessing what the question's author have tried already.

Comment: So why not ask, and wait, for clarification instead of posting a potentially (likely) worthless answer...

Comment: But i want to find the part from href=" to " out of a string, and then do the urlencode()

Comment: @Pekka웃 I assumed this can help. And if not the author clarifies why not.

Comment: @qwertz in that case, you'll need a HTML parser. [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641)

Comment: @Pekka웃 The OP stated "How to do this? preg_replace?" which implies he/she is using PHP in the HTML (via <?php ?> tags or something). That is why I answered with PHP.

It's easy to do <a href="<?php #codehere ?>">.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
<a href="<? echo(urlencode("Replace the spaces here")); ?>">Some text</a>
```

Comment: Yes, i want to find the part from href=" to " out of a string, and then do the urlencode()

Comment: @qwertz consider responding to our requests for clarification then

Comment: @qwertz1029384756 So, are you saying you are parsing existing html rather than writing a new page? (Incidentally I cannot yet ask for clarification on the main question itself.)